# Input text field that only accepts numbers dash numbers

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to control input field using jQuery previously i had only numbers and could use      `$(this).autoNumeric()`, now i have come around where it is required to change the input field in form of 'Numbers dash Numbers'.

I have tried few links from this site as well as others without any success, 
I am just beginner of UI, pls help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use a regular expression.   I wouldn't rely solely on HTML5 input masks.

```
/^\d+(-\d+)*$/
```

should suffice if there's no stronger constraints.

```
$("#myfield").change(function(){ 
  var isValid = $(this).val().match(/^\d+(-\d+)*$/);
  if(!isValid){
    alert('only numbers and hyphesn please');
    return false;
 }
});
```

simple html:

```
<input id="myfield">
```

demo:  http://jsbin.com/jeziqifebu/1/edit

---

UPDATE:

User wants numberstrings, ie 3.4.5 not just decimal figures.

```
 $("#myfield").change(function(){ 
    var pattern = /^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?(\.\d{1,2})?(-\d+(\.\d{1,2})?(\.\d{1,2})?)?$/;
    var isValid = $(this).val().match(pattern);
    if(!isValid){
       alert('only numbers or valid range separated by hyphens please');
     return false;
   }
});
```

this will take

```
2
2-3
2.3
2.3-4
2.3.4-5
2.3.4-5.6
2.3.4-5.6.7
```

Demo:  http://jsbin.com/hivikudova/2/edit

Comment: I mean 3.4.0-54.0, but it is allowing other characters too.

Comment: I am using through class but it is not working, Doing something like this, and it is allowing all the chars to get entered which i want to restrict
  `$('.left_length').change( function() {
                var pattern = /^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?(\.\d{1,2})?(-\d+                            (\.\d{1,2})?(\.\d{1,2})?)?$/;
                var isValid = $(this).val().match(pattern);
                 if(!isValid){
                  alert('only numbers or valid range separated by hyphens please');
                  return false;
                  }

            
            });`

Comment: thanks briansol... your solution solved my problem partially...like allowing to enter but i did some workaround and solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesnt allow you to enter anything but numbers and a single dash: [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/J6B7U/79/)

```
<input onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);">

var dashCount = 0;
function isNumberKey(evt)
{
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode == 45) {
        dashCount++;
    }
    if ((charCode > 47 && charCode <58) || (charCode == 45 && dashCount < 2))
    {
        return true;
    }
  return false;
}
```